# How to display binary data in <img /> in browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, httprequest, binary-data

Data in mongodb looks like:

```
avatar:Binary('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoEAmpwR42ny9h3db17Xuq//g...', 0)
```

Data in response using postman looks like:

```
{
  "avatar": {
       "type": "Buffer",
       "data": [137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,8,...]
   }
}
```

Now, how can I display these datas in  in browser?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it directly in the html:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{binary data}" />
```

Comment: This is not a good solution to the problem.  Base64 adds 33% in overhead, not to mention the additional bloat of dealing with it in the Document itself.  There is no need to use base64 in this case.

Comment: @Brad how would you do it, without requiring him to save a copy of the image and wait for the <img> request?

Comment: @TimRoberts You can still use an `<img>` tag in the HTML, but stream the response directly out of MongoDB to the client.  The tag would be something like `<img src="https://node.example.com/avatar/some-id" />`, and the Node.js server would respond with the binary data of the image.  Don't forget the appropriate `Content-Type` HTTP response header.

Comment: @TimRoberts If the data is client-side, you can also take the Blob and use `URL.createObjectURL` for it.

Comment: @md-moinul I did the same but the image is not displayed in the browser.